# Display categories and sub-categories

Tags: category, category-products, category-tree

I'm tryng to display categories and subcategories on a cms page

```
<?php 
    $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addIsActiveFilter();
    foreach ($_categories->getStoreCategories() as     $_category) { 
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category'); 
        $category->load($_category->getId()); 
        $subcategories = explode(',', $category->getChildren()); 
?> 
        <dl> 
          <dt><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()); ?>
          </dt> 
          <dd> 
            <ol> 
              <?php 
                foreach ($subcategories as $subcategoryId) { 
                  $category->load($subcategoryId); 
                  echo '<li><a href="' . $category->getURL() . '">' . $category->getName() . '</a></li>'; 
                } 
              ?> 
            </ol> 
          </dd> 
        </dl> 
    <?php
      } 
    ?>
```

But this is returning me a fatal error Fatal error: Call to a member function getStoreCategories() on null on line 5

Comment: change $_categories->getStoreCategories()  to $categories->getStoreCategories()  i thing $_categories variabale is not define there

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code for display all store category and subcategories.

```
<?php
    $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
    $categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories();

    foreach ($categories as $_category) {
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
        $subcategories = $category->getChildrenCategories();
        ?>
        <dl>
            <dt><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()); ?></dt>
            <dd>
                <ol>
                    <?php
                    foreach ($subcategories as $_subcategory) {
                        echo '<li><a href="' . $_subcategory->getURL() . '">' . $_subcategory->getName() . '</a></li>';
                    }
                    ?>
                </ol>
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <?php

    }
    ?>
```

Let me know if you have any query from above.

Comment: This will only work in one level, if subcategories have their own subcategories then?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below steps:

Step 1: Create **new_list.phtml** in `frontend/your_theme/default/template/catalog/category` and paste the below code :

```
     ================code starts here================

<div class="block block-list block-categories">
    <div id="block-categories" class="block-title active">
        <strong><span>Categories </span></strong>
    </div>  
    <div id="leftnav" class="block-content" style="display:block">
        <?php $helper = $this->helper('catalog/category') ?>
            <?php $categories = $this->getStoreCategories() ?>
        <?php if (count($categories) > 0): ?>
            <ul id="leftnav-tree" class="level0">
                <?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
                    <li class="level0<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($category)): ?> active<?php endif; ?>">
                        <a href="<?php echo $helper->getCategoryUrl($category) ?>"><span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) ?></span></a>
                        <?php //if ($this->isCategoryActive($category)): ?>
                            <?php $subcategories = $category->getChildren() ?>
                            <?php if (count($subcategories) > 0): ?>
                                <ul id="leftnav-tree-<?php echo $category->getId() ?>" class="level1">
                                    <?php foreach($subcategories as $subcategory): ?>
                                        <li class="level1<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($subcategory)): ?> active<?php endif; ?>">
                                            <a href="<?php echo $helper->getCategoryUrl($subcategory) ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml(trim($subcategory->getName(), '- ')) ?></a>
                                             <?php $secondLevelSubcategories = $subcategory->getChildren() ?>
                                             <?php if (count($secondLevelSubcategories ) > 0): ?>
                                <ul id="leftnav-tree-<?php echo $subcategory->getId() ?>" class="level2">
                                    <?php foreach($secondLevelSubcategories as $secondLevelSubcategory ): ?>
                                        <li class="level2<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($secondLevelSubcategory )): ?> active<?php endif; ?>">
                                            <a href="<?php echo $helper->getCategoryUrl($secondLevelSubcategory ) ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml(trim($secondLevelSubcategory ->getName(), '- ')) ?></a>
                                        </li>
                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </ul>
                                <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('leftnav-tree-<?php echo $category->getId() ?>', 'recursive')</script>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </ul>
                                <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('leftnav-tree-<?php echo $category->getId() ?>', 'recursive')</script>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php //endif; ?>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
            <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('leftnav-tree', 'recursive')</script>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>

          ===============code ends here===============
```

Step 2 : Call **new_list.phtml** in your CMS page or static block:

```
{{block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.category" template="catalog/category/new_list.phtml"}}
```

Hope, it will help.